# Modify global variable defined outside of table inside the table

Tags: birt

I have a persistent global variable set outside an inner table and inside that inner table I am modifying the value then I want to retrieve it after the inner table is done doing its functionality. I noticed when I retrieve the value inside the inner table and append the necessary then display the new values inside the inner table row it shows but when I want to retrieve variable after table modifies, the data I use to the global doesn't show the modified variable, is there maybe something I am doing wrong.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your scripts and from which method event they are invoked, it would help to pinpoint the precise cause of the problem.

As you describe it, most likely your inner Table is updating this variable through an "onRender" event, it would explain why this is not available in other elements. When we deal with persistent variable we should never update its value in render events, unless being very comfortable with BIRT elements lifecycle.